# Splitting big files based on value in a column in the file

Tags: awk

I have a large file of size 38000 by 5001. The first column is position information and the rest are signals. I also have another file that contains pairs of positions that also exists in the large files. I need to split the large file into multiple small files where each file only contains the rows that are in a certain range.

I know this is almost a duplicate question and I have tried everything that is provided before. It's not working that's why I'm posting here my codes. I have tried with `awk`. Here's what I've tried.

The file that contains the pairs of ranges is named with the lowest and highest value. For example, the name of a range file I have can be `blah_blah_30000_4000.txt`. This file contains pair values in every 500 apart. Such as

```
30000    30000
30000    30500
30000    31000
.
.
.
40000    30000
40000    30500
.
.
.
40000    40000
```

First I extracted the lowest and highest value from the file name.

```
IFS='_' read -a splittedName <<< "${fileName}"
startRange=${splittedName[2]}
endRange=${splittedName[3]}
```

Now to make these two strings into numbers

```
starting=$((startRange + 0))
ending=$((endRange + 0))
```

Then I used `awk` like so

```
awk -F, '{ if($1 >= "$startRange" && $1 <= "$endRange") { print >"test.txt"} }' $InputFile
```

Could anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The data is pre-sorted by first column??

Comment: *I also have another file that contains pairs of positions that also exists in the large files.* Can you elaborate on this? Is this one file or two files?

Comment: You try to use shell variables in an awk script. That is not the way to do it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671. However, be aware that, if we have a bit more information about your input files, we could probably write a single awk script that does it all in a single go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite your command on this way:

```
awk -F, -v start=$startRange -v end=$endRange -v fname=$fileName\
'{ if($1 >= start && $1 <= end) { print >$fname.txt} }' $InputFile
```

As mentioned in comments you can't use shell variables inside awk script

Comment: Thanks, @Romeo. It worked and also learned new thing.